# Multiple integral variable change

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to calculate the integral $$n_2\sigma\int\int f_1(\mathbf{v_1})d\mathbf{v_1}f_2(\mathbf{v_2})d\mathbf{v_2}|\mathbf{v_1-v_2}|$$ over all space. Note that $d\mathbf{v_1}$ and $d\mathbf{v_2}$ are velocity space, so to be clear I should probably write them as $d^3\mathbf{v_1}$ and $d^3\mathbf{v_2}$. This is a six dimensional integral with each of the six velocity components going from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Before I introduce the functional forms of $f_1$ and $f_2$ (although telling you that they are Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distributions for molecules in a gas may be of some help) let me just consider a simpler case, which is
$$n\sigma\int\int f(\mathbf{v_1})d\mathbf{v_1}f(\mathbf{v_2})d\mathbf{v_2}|\mathbf{v_1-v_2}|$$
with $f(\mathbf{x})=(\frac{m}{2\pi kT})^{\frac{3}2}e^{\frac{-mx^2}{2kT}}$.
Here, we can solve by substituting $u=\frac{v_1-v_2}{\sqrt2}$ and $v=\frac{v_1+v_2}{\sqrt2}$. This is because of the nature of $f(\mathbf{x})$, because then the integral reduces to $$\sqrt2n\sigma\int\int f(\mathbf{u})d\mathbf{u}f(\mathbf{v})d\mathbf{v}|\mathbf{u}|$$. Now $f(\mathbf{x})$ is a normalized probability distribution so this gives us $\sqrt2 n\sigma<v>$ where $<v>$ represents the mean of either of the two velocites as they have the same distributions (the other integral gives unity thanks to the normalization).

Returning to the original problem, I can define $f_1(\mathbf{v_1})=(\frac{m_1}{2\pi kT})^{\frac{3}2}e^{\frac{-m_1v_1^2}{2kT}}$ and $f_2(\mathbf{v_2})=(\frac{m_2}{2\pi kT})^{\frac{3}2}e^{\frac{-m_2v_2^2}{2kT}}$ and so this isn't too much of a big change from the problem we already solved. Writing this out, we obtain
$$n_2\sigma\int\int\frac{(m_1m_2)^{\frac{3}2}}{(2\pi kT)^3}e^{-\frac{(m_1v_1^2+m_2v_2^2)}{2kT}}|\mathbf{v_1-v_2}|d\mathbf{v_1}d\mathbf{v_2}$$
and so it seems to just be a question of being clever enough to think of the change of variable. With this fundamentally having stemmed from a physics problem, I believe the reduced mass $\frac{1}{\mu}=\frac{1}{m_1}+\frac{1}{m_2}$ might try to get involved. Would anybody be able to offer any guidance? Thankyou :)